# add new coordinates to an xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

Assume the following code, which has an `xarray.DataArray` with two dimensions and a coordinate:

```py
import numpy as np
from xarray import DataArray

data = np.random.rand(10, 4)
f_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
sample_weights = np.random.rand(10)
rows = list(range(len(data)))
coords={'samples': rows,
        'features': f_names,
        'sample_weights': ('samples', sample_weights)}
xdata = DataArray(data, coords=coords,
                  dims=['samples', 'features'])

subset = xdata[::2]
```

Now I want to add another coordinates, like `alternate_sample_weights` to `subset`. I try:

```py
subset.assign_coords(alternate_sample_weights=np.zeros(5)
```

which results in the following error:

```py
ValueError: cannot add coordinates with new dimensions to a DataArray
```

The [API documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.assign_coords.html#xarray.DataArray.assign_coords) is pretty sparse, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when adding a new coordinate, you need to pass also the dimension along which it's added. So in this case, it would be:

```py
subset.assign_coords(
    alternate_sample_weights=('samples', np.zeros(5)))
```