# Preserve coordinates in xarray.Dataset when subsetting a DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to have multiple coordinate systems for a given dimension, e.g., a single `"time"` dimension with coordinates for (the default) `datetime64[ns]` type but also for a numeric year, or a season. This seems to be possible using `Dataset.assign_coords()` but has some unexpected behavior when subsetting a `DataArray` within the `Dataset`.

I'm using [the publicly available NASA dataset available here](https://archive.podaac.earthdata.nasa.gov/podaac-ops-cumulus-protected/TELLUS_GRAC-GRFO_MASCON_CRI_GRID_RL06.1_V3/GRCTellus.JPL.200204_202311.GLO.RL06.1M.MSCNv03CRI.nc) (with Earthdata login); described in more detail [at this link](https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/TELLUS_GRAC-GRFO_MASCON_CRI_GRID_RL06.1_V3).

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.open_mfdataset('GRCTellus.JPL.200204_202311.GLO.RL06.1M.MSCNv03CRI.nc')
ds.coords['lon'] = ds.coords['lon'] - 180

# Get a list of all the dates from the "time" coordinate
dates = ds.coords['time'].values

# Convert each "datetime64[ns]" object to a 4-digit year
years = []
for each in dates:
    years.append(int(str(each)[0:4]))

# Create a new set of coordinates
ds = ds.assign_coords(year = ('year', years))
```

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (lat: 360, time: 227, lon: 720, bounds: 2, year: 227)
Coordinates:
  * lat            (lat) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 ... 88.75 89.25 89.75
  * time           (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-17T12:00:00 ... 2023-11-16
  * lon            (lon) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 ... 178.8 179.2 179.8
  * year           (year) int64 2002 2002 2002 2002 2002 ... 2023 2023 2023 2023
```

This works great, so far, in that I have a `year` coordinate now. **I also have a `year` dimension listed, which is not what I wanted.**

The more serious problem is that when I select a `DataArray` from this `Dataset`, it doesn't know anything about the new coordinates.

```py
ds['lwe_thickness'].sel(lon = slice(-124, -114), lat = slice(32, 42))
```

```
<xarray.DataArray 'lwe_thickness' (time: 227, lat: 20, lon: 20)>
dask.array<getitem, shape=(227, 20, 20), dtype=float64, chunksize=(46, 20, 20), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 32.25 32.75 33.25 33.75 ... 40.25 40.75 41.25 41.75
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-17T12:00:00 ... 2023-11-16
  * lon      (lon) float64 -123.8 -123.2 -122.8 -122.2 ... -115.2 -114.8 -114.2
```

The result is that `"time"` is listed as a coordinate, but not `"year"`. This has implications for using [`DataArray.polyfit()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.polyfit.html#xarray.DataArray.polyfit), because without a `"year"` coordinate I can't get coefficient values denominated by year.

**How can I make a new coordinate system available to each `DataArray` in my `Dataset`?** I have looked at:

- ["add new coordinates to an xarray.DataArray"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951314/add-new-coordinates-to-an-xarray-dataarray) - But when I try this, I get a `ValueError: cannot add coordinates with new dimensions to a DataArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it to connect the new coordinate to a newly created dimension 'year'. I didn't try this on your exact data, but try connecting the coordinate 'year' to the existing dimension 'time'

```
 ds = ds.assign_coords(year = ('time', years))
```

Then the 'year' coordinate should also show up in the DataArrays that are defined over the dimension 'time'.